# What is the area of the apollonian gaskets?

Tags: measure-theory, fractals

I searched for the internet, but found nothing relavant to the area.

The areas in each intermediate step form a bounded increasing sequence, so there is a limit. But wil it eventually fill in almost everywhere?

Comment: It sums to twice the area of the outer circle (i.e. the circles fill up everywhere). I come across this result in this [paper](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~staff/RTGPapers/ApollonianSums.pdf) which talks about how to perform sum over the radii appear in the apollonian gasket.

Comment: Not twice the area (which makes no sense) but the area of the outer circle. The reason is that the residual set has zero area.

Comment: @studiosus, but how to prove that? The series for area seems complicated.

Comment: @studiosus the sum I mentioned include the outer circle.

Comment: @achillehui: Oh, sorry, I did not understand the way you count.

Answer (score 2):

The Hausdorff dimension of the residual set $R$ of the Appolonian gasket is approximately $1.3$ (definitely less than $1.4$), see the discussion and references [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119127/apollonian-gasket-and-the-degree-of-convergence). In particular, the 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure of $R$ is zero (this was known, I think, long before 1982). Hence the total area of the inner circles of the gasket is the same as the area of the outer circle.